# Change DB Connection dynamically

Tags: laravel, database

I want to make an application using Laravel.
this application has 2 databases (production and sandbox).
when we log in, we can change production or sandbox by using the dropdown.
my question is:

1. How to achieve this?
2. Where I must place the table user? one of that databases or create a third database? how about the table relation?

Comment: I would say, you must create a staging environment, and have all the test code in there.... if by sandbox you mean "test something in your app" because your app is about coding, or whatever (you just want production with a fake database so user can try stuff), then it should be another schema, and you use production for mostly everything. You are talking about "where must I place the table user?", that sounds a staging enviroment for me, not a sandbox environment... explain more please

Comment: my point is this admin dashboard that they have 2 environments prod and sandbox. they can switch to see data from selected environment in one dashboard

Answer (score 0):

1. You could set the config to a session variable using a middleware like

```
config(['database.default' => Session::get('db_to_use')]);
```

2. Keep all the users in one table and then set the connection in the User model like

```
/**
 * The database connection that should be used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $connection = 'prod';
```

(from https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#database-connections)

## However

My 2 cents:

This seems quite dangerous having changes to production be so easily accessible. I would keep the databases separated by more than a dropdown.

ex. You are making changes to the sandbox site and open a new tab, switch to production from the dropdown, and make other changes. You then go back to your original tab and see the dropdown says 'sandbox' and make some changes, but *UHOH*, you deleted someone's report that is due today.

Comment: yeah, of course, I separated the production and sandbox database with different connections and servers. So, in the application user can see data from both environments in a single app by switching using the dropdown.